# Creating a DHCP server on a Virtual Machine

Tags: networking, windows-8, virtualbox, dhcp-server, pfsense

i have a Windows 8 machine with PFsense in virtual box.
The host have the following nics:

1. Wi-fi
2. Ethernet

I have 3 network adaptares on the virtual Machine:

1. Wan (Bridged adapter through host's wi-fi)
2. Lan (host only adapter)
3. OPT1 (Bridged adapter through host's ethernet)

What i'm trying to achieve is i want to connect a router to the host's ethernet, so PFsense assign an ip address to my router, so i can connect wirelessly to the router, and the router go directly through pfsense, and finally coming out from pfsense through the wireless of the host. I'm doing this because i'm just checking a captive portal that i've made, it's working on the local host adapter, but i wanted to try outside. Any help? It's just a practice for my school.

Answer (score 0):

From the explenation you're giving I'm assuming that the pfsense is your main router / firewall, while you have another router which you would like to connect to over wireless.

Firstly it doesn't make sense to have a router obtain an IP from DHCP; assign the router with a static IP and connect to it and perform any configuration to it.

Once your pfsense, router and computer you're working from, are on the same subnet you should be able to access them by using a web browser to browse to their IP: 
e.g. router: 192.168.1.1, router: 192.168.1.2 and computer: 192.168.1.3
The default gateway should be your pfsense.

Comment: Ohh Sorry for replying this late.

But the router which ip has to be the default gateway? The OPT1 nic isn't it? I tried to put a static IP address to the router so i can connect the wan port to my PC so any connection goes directly to PFSense, so i can get to the captive portal.

Comment: Also i don't know if i'm getting like too confused, but i'm trying to connect the wan port of the router to my pc.

Comment: I've made it! Thanks for your help! now it's working.